# Does a DCM flyback always operate in CCM during startup?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

In the flyback topology :
When dimensioned for fixed frequency discontinuous mode, to me it seems unavoidable that the converter will operate in CCM during startup since v=L*di/dt.
And since the output voltage is (almost) zero,
The slope —di/dt is very slow/low, so the current will not be zero before the switch turns on again.

The question:
Can this lead to problems?And what kind of?
Or is it not important since this only happens for a short time.

Comment: I don't agree with your premise. At start-up the duty cycle is miniscule (slowly ramping from zero to some fixed regulation point over many switching cycles in a soft-start) so the energy stored during the short on-time is quickly and completely transferred during the off-time - the majority of the off-time is dead time, so it's extremely deep DCM and not CCM at all.

Comment: I somehow cannot agree : IC’s usually have a minimum on-time to prevent false turn off. So there will be always a minimun ton, if the output voltage is zero. Then the energy/current cannot be transfered to the load right?or at least very slowly

Comment: @AdamLawrence at start up its nearly impossible to transfer the energy stored very quickly at all and, for this reason, the inductor remains charged at the end of the normal switching cycle. Transferring full energy when the output capacitor has built up To nearly full voltage is easier because di/dt is greater. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of them do just that. The other option is to ramp up in DCM (with no dwell time which is obviously the border with CCM) very slowly and the reason is (and I suspect you know) is that charging the output capacitor up from 0 volts cannot be done quickly because the slope of the current passed into the capacitor is naturally very low hence, the energy transfer is quite small.

The slope of the current (from the charged inductor) multiplied by its inductance equals the voltage on the output capacitor hence, because the voltage is close to 0 volts initially, the inductor cannot dispense much of its energy in the regular switching cycle.

If you tried to do it in CCM you could run up quicker but you might easily over stress the inductor.

Comment: can you also indicate if this can lead to any issues ? for example that the control goes crazy ?

Comment: Changing from DCM to. CCM can cause craziness if the loop cannot handle the sudden change in loop damping factor. That's the usual problem but modern day chips are quite sophisticated and it's not much of a problem.